# Provide initial data for Django models from txt file

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, txt, django-database

I have a [.txt file](https://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/distfromcoast/) with 3 columns (longitude, latitude, distance) and 40 million rows.
These are the first lines of the file.

```
-179.98 89.98   712.935
-179.94 89.98   712.934
-179.9  89.98   712.933
-179.86 89.98   712.932
-179.82 89.98   712.932
-179.78 89.98   712.931
-179.74 89.98   712.93
-179.7  89.98   712.929
-179.66 89.98   712.928
-179.62 89.98   712.927
```

Is there a way to provide these 40 million rows as initial data to this Django model?

```
from django.db import models

class Location(models.Model):

    longitude = models.FloatField()
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    distance = models.FloatField()
```

Comment: Totally doable.  You need to perform the following actions - namely, open the text file (40 million rows may be a HEAVY file), read each line, split the line into three variables, and create a model instance with each variable.  Do this in a loop.  Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

This is fully untested code, but you could try something like:

```
import os
from your_app.models import Location

with open('path/to/your_text_file.txt') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    for line in data:
        coords_and_dist = line.split(' ')
        try:
           Location.objects.create(longitude=float(coords_and_dist[0]),
                                   latitude=float(coords_and_dist[1]),
                                   distance=float(coords_and_dist[2])
        except:
            pass
```

You may run into some performance and memory issues with 40 million lines, I have not run something like this on a text file that big.